# Label last page in sequence of \includepdf commands

Tags: environments, page-numbering, pdfpages, auxiliary-files, lastpage

I am in a tricky situation. I am using NewEnviron to separate a handful of major parts of my document. Each part has its own numbering scheme and several environment-specific commands and settings. Important for my question, all numbering schemes follow the principle `page_current of page_total`

If I now, however, insert pdf-documents using `\includepdf`, the label for `page_total` breaks if `\includepdf` is executed on the last page of my document.

Here an mwe, which probably explains it a bit better.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mwe}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\NewEnviron{myenvi}{%
    \clearscrheadfoot%
    \cfoot{\normalfont\thepage\ / \pageref{lastpage}}%
    \clearpage%
    \BODY%
    \label{lastpage}%
}

\newcommand{\myincludepdf}[1]{\includepdf[scale=0.5, frame, pagecommand={}]{#1}}
%\newcommand{\myincludepdf}[1]{\includepdf[scale=0.5, frame, pagecommand={\label{lastpage}}]{#1}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{myenvi}
        \lipsum[1-15]
        \myincludepdf{example-image-a4}
    \end{myenvi}

\end{document}
```

I also tried to add my label to the post-code of includepdf. That doesn't help.

I found two ways to get it to work. But both are not satisfactory. The first one is simply to add another page to the document. Because then the `\label{lastpage}` can execute again. Moreover, one can also add the `\label{lastpage}` to the pagecommand-option of \includepdf. But then I get a lot of "lastpage multiply defined" warnings.

Anyone an idea how to solve this issue. I was considering using a counter or gdef or something. But I think it is not really possible to get around this problem without the help of a sidecar-file.

Is there maybe an option to directly manipulate the aux-file so that I don't produce multiple labels and only the last call of `\label{lastpage}` remains?

Comment: Do you get the multiply labels because the pdf has more than one page (which is hasn't in your example)?

Comment: If you call `includepdf` more than once, the warnings occur even if you don't use the `pagecommand={\label{lastpage}` option. Just ignore them - warnings are warnings and not errors for a reason.

Comment: Yes, the warnings only occur if I call \includepdf multiple times. But that is the idea. I want to use that to add certificates to my CV. 

And I, unfortunately, can not ignore the warnings. In the end, I would like to put everything in a document class and share it with my colleagues. Therefore, I would like to keep random warnings to a minimum.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found a solution. Probably also not the most elegant one, but it works.
I use the *lastpage*-package to check inside `\includepdf` whether the current page is the last one of the document or not. If that is the case, I execute `\label{endenvi}` and, hence, only define it once. And if a page comes after all `\includepdf`'s the label-command inside my environment-definition executes.

Here the code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mwe}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}


\NewEnviron{myenvi}{%
    \clearscrheadfoot%
    \cfoot{\normalfont\thepage\ / \pageref{endenvi}}%
    \clearpage%
    \BODY%
    \label{endenvi}
}


\newcommand{\myincludepdf}[1]{\includepdf[scale=0.5, frame, pagecommand={%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\pageref{LastPage}}{\thepage}}{\label{endenvi}}{}}]{#1}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{myenvi}
        \lipsum[1-15]
        \myincludepdf{example-image-a4}
        \myincludepdf{example-image-a4}
    \end{myenvi}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you only want to set `\label{endenvi}` if you are on the last page, why don't you the `LastPage` label directly?